# Python Beautifulsoup find element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find titles, dates, and links from a website, I use:

```
html_link = 'https://xueqiu.com/u/4357540281'
html = requests.get(html_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
boxes=soup.select("timeline__item__main")
search = re.compile("今天")
data = []  
for box in boxes:
    print(box)
    titles = box.find("span").getText()
    dates = box.find("a").getText().replace(", ", " ")
    links = f'https://xueqiu.com/{box.find("a")["href"]}'  
    print(titles,dates,links)     
    for text in box.find_all("a",text=search):
        names = text.text
        data.append([titles, dates, names, links])
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Titles', 'Dates', 'Names', 'Links'])
```

But return am empty dataframe, could someone please help if something go wrong with the codes?
Many thanks!!

Comment: What do you see if you try `print(titles,dates,links,names))`  within the  `for text in box.find_all("a",text=search):`?

Comment: The entire page is behind `JavaScript` so you're not getting what you're looking for in the source `HTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the endpoint to get the user timeline data.

Here's how:

```python
import requests

with requests.Session() as connection:
    connection.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
    _ = connection.get("https://xueqiu.com")
    user_timeline = connection.get("https://xueqiu.com/v4/statuses/user_timeline.json?page=1&user_id=4357540281").json()
    for status in user_timeline["statuses"]:
        print(
            "\n".join(
                [
                    status["timeBefore"],
                    status["title"],
                    f'https://xueqiu.com{status["target"]}',
                ]
            )
        )
```

Output:

```
今天 16:49
标普：予金科地产(000656.SZ)拟发行美元高级票据“B+”评级
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180404598
今天 16:42
惠誉：首予中裕燃气(03633.HK)“B+”长期外币发行人评级，展望“正面”
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180403813
今天 15:52
惠誉：予国任保险“BBB+”长期发行人评级，展望“稳定”
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180398328
今天 15:27
惠誉：确认中航资本(600705.SH)“A-”长期发行人信用评级，展望“稳定”
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180394785
今天 15:10
惠誉：确认中国船舶租赁(03877.HK)“A”长期发行人评级，展望“稳定”
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180392812
今天 15:05
惠誉：确认招商租赁“BBB+”长期发行人评级，展望“稳定”
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180391975
今天 14:54
惠誉：确认中航国际租赁长期发行人评级为“A-”，展望“稳定”
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180390295
今天 14:32
中裕燃气(03633.HK)拟发行美元票据，今日起召开投资者电话会议
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180386999
今天 14:26
国任保险拟发行两笔高级无抵押票据，今日起召开投资者电话会议
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180386012
今天 14:13
金科股份(000656.SZ)拟发行美元票据，今日起召开投资者电话会议
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180384058
今天 13:48
长兴城投拟发行3年期绿色美元债券，初始价2.8%区域，徽商银行(03698.HK)提供SBLC
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180380623
今天 11:53
南宁交投集团拟发行3年期美元高级票据，初始价3.90%区域
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180367887
今天 11:07
惠誉：出于商业原因，撤销朗诗地产(00106.HK)“B”长期外币发行人评级
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180361023
今天 11:02
惠誉：首予济南高新控股“BBB”长期本外币发行人评级，展望“稳定”
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180360220
今天 09:57
天誉置业(00059.HK)拟对SKYFAM 13 12/16/23进行增发，最终指导价13%
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180346688
05-19 14:40
标普：予江苏沙钢集团“BBB-”长期发行人信用评级，展望“稳定”
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180271248
05-19 14:35
惠誉：出于商业原因，撤销金轮天地(01232.HK)“CCC+”长期本外币发行人评级
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180270515
05-19 14:10
惠誉：确认中国交建(01800.HK)“A-”长期外币发行人评级，展望“稳定”
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180267003
05-19 10:19
惠誉：上调金鹰商贸集团(03308.HK)长期发行人评级至“BB+”，展望“稳定”
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180237685
05-19 10:09
标普：下调温氏股份(300498.SZ)发行人信用评级至“BBB-”，展望“稳定”
https://xueqiu.com/4357540281/180235626
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! may I know why my code does not work? and what if I also want the dates and links

Comment: Your code doesn't work because, as I've said in the comment under your question, the entire site is behind `JavaScript`, which means you don't get the HTML you think you get.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! how could I identify a Javascript? or is that possible to use selenium? sorry just one more question, could I set only return data under the condition: ```Timebefore``` = 今天？

Comment: This is just a sample code, so you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: thanks! but I am not familiar with Java, should I use```status["timeBefore": '今天']```?